# Projecting a SpatialLines object from lat/lon to utm

Tags: r, projection, utm, great-circle

I created a great-circle trajectory of lat/lon using the `geosphere` package:

```
flightTraj  = greatCircle( c( originAptLon, originAptLat ), c( destinAptLon, destinAptLat ), n = nPts, sp = TRUE )
```

Its properties are:

```
class       : SpatialLines 
features    : 1 
extent      : -180, 180, -52.74719, 52.74719  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84
```

I want to project to a UTM zone 14 cartography with WGS84 ellipsoid.  I tried:

```
projectedTrajectories  <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs") %>% 
    spTransform( flightTraj, . )
```

But, the console displayed:

```
non finite transformation detected:
  V1 lat  
  Error in .spTransform_Line(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
  failure in Lines 1 Line 1 points 
  In addition: Warning message:
  In .spTransform_Line(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args =     from_args,  :
  6 projected point(s) not finite
```

Any help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All's well that ends well..."

```
distOrigDest = distGeo( c( originAptLon, originAptLat ), c( destinAptLon, destinAptLat ), a = earthRadius, f = earthFlattening ) / km2m 
nPts = 20 * floor( distOrigDest / cellCentroidDist )
flightTraj = gcIntermediate( c( originAptLon, originAptLat ), c( destinAptLon, destinAptLat ), n = nPts, sp = TRUE )
flightTraj  = spTransform( flightTraj, "+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=km" )
plot( flightTraj, col= "blue", add = TRUE, lwd = 2 )
```